# Autoincrement whil using $push

Tags: mongodb

I try to add an `auto increment id` for `sub-documents` using this:

```
db.users.update({"pup.avt.fto": var},{"$push":{"pup.$.cmn":{"txt": cmnt, {"id":{"$inc":1}}}}})
```

But it dont work!

What am i doing wrong?

here is what i got (used Fang of Mongo)

as you can see, there i want to add an `id` and increment it:

```
{
 "adr": {
 "wil": "15",
 "com": "Azazga",
 "sit": "http://peugeot.dz",
 "cor": [
    36.743954,
    4.365041
        ]
},
"_id": "abdelouahab_al@yahoo.fr",
"pup": [
 {
  "avt": {
  "fto": {
  "$oid": "516ff3e03a5f3a0eec7c4e2b"
 },
"ori": "portrait"
 },
"cmn": [
 {
 "txt": "this is the comment that i want to add the increment id"
 },
       ],
},
}
```

Comment: Can you give the initial and the final document ( after update query ).
I am not able to correctly get your update query.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar i updated the question and added the schema

Comment: There is a documented pattern explaining how to implement auto incremente at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: thank you, but it seems there is not way (at this moment) to use $inc directylt everytime a subdocument is added